# std::array size set at class wrapper instantiation

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

```
class A {};

class B{
private:
   size_t arraySize;
   unique_ptr<array<A, arraySize>> upArrayA;

public:
    B(size_t tArraySize) 
      : arraySize(tArraySize), upArrayA(make_unique<array<A,arraySize>>())
    {}
};

B b(3);    //would like to set array size here
```

The above code does not work because arraySize is not static const.

I know array needs compile time knowledge of size but that is the case with normal C arrays too.  Yet with C arrays you can use the dynamic syntax to bypass this requirement.

Is there some ninja magic way that I can set the size of the array at object instantiation?

Comment: std::array is meant to have a static compile-time known size. If you want dynamic sizing, then std::vector is what you need to look at

Comment: On the other hand, if you know the size before hand. Then you can template class `B` on that size. So `template <std::size_t arraySize> class B {};`

Comment: Technically, the compiler should be able to deduce size fromt he above code.  I'm not asking the user for size at run time.  Perhaps templating would work.  Or some other trick.

Comment: @code - The rule is that all objects of the same type must have the same size, `sizeof(B)`. So you wouldn't be able to create `B`s with different parameters anyway.

Comment: I think constexpr is what you might be after.  If it can be deduced at compile time constexpr should be able to do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template the class based on the size:

```
template <std::size_t arraySize> 
class B {
private:
   unique_ptr<std::array<A, arraySize>> upArrayA;

public:
    B() : upArrayA(std::make_unique<>()) {}
};
```

---

Usage looks like:

```
B<3> b;
```

Comment: "set the size of the array at object instantiation". OP needs std::vector.